# Field sort random via PHP

Tags: 7, entities

I have a image field and use on cycle.

field.tpl.php:

```
<?php
?>

<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

My field items sorting default alphabetical but i want random. How can i do this?

EDIT: I find this codes, it valid for me? And how can i use this code for my field?

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
 if($variables['element']['#field_name']=="field_project_release_packages"){
 usort($variables["items"], "_my_theme_sort_package_list");
 }
}

function _my_theme_sort_package_list($a, $b) {
    return $a["#title"] > $b["#title"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [template_preprocess_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) and [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to do this. This is an example randomizing the entries in field_photo for a theme called dummy:

```
  function dummy_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_photo') {
      shuffle($variables['items']);
    }
  }
```

You could also try to replacing you call to `usort()` in your original code with `shuffle($variables["items"])`.

The above isn't tested, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thank you, put this code on my template.php and edited but don't work.

Comment: I just tried it locally and it seems to work just fine? Have you changed the `<TEMPLATE>` to the name of your theme and the `<YOURFIELDNAME>` to the name of the field your are trying to modify? Also, make sure you empty your cache.

Comment: You shouldn't mark this as correct if it doesn't work...

Comment: Actually, the answer is marked as accepted, not as correct. It means the answer helped the OP. As for not working, it could be the OP edited the template.php file of an already enabled theme; if that is the case, new hooks/theme functions are not found from Drupal, which caches some of the functions implemented by a module, or a theme.